# Jagged array in cython

Tags: python, numpy, cython, jagged-arrays

If I have a jagged list in python like

```
jagged = [[1],[2,3]]
```

how can I declare it as an array using numpy and cython?
Is it possible somehow?
I know the following syntax, but it won't do, as it gives only a 1D array.

```
cdef numpy.ndarray[np.float_t] jagged
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Numpy arrays (both in and out of Cython) are typically rectangular.  You don't say what you're trying to do with the jagged array, but you might be able to use:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html

or:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html

As for the 1-dimensional part of your question, you're wanting the ndim param (mode='c' can speed things up if you won't be getting any order='F' arrays):

```
cdef numpy.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2, mode='c'] somearray
```